# The computer sees a portable USB disk... but there is no disk connected

Tags: hard-drive, usb, bios, removable-media

Good morning,

I have a problem with USB/removable disk detection in my computer **(System - Windows 10 Home / Motherboard - MSI B450-A PRO / Processor - AMD Ryzen 5 2600 3.9GHz, 16MB)**

In BIOS I can see two physical disks (system on SSD and data on HDD). And it's OK.

And now for the thing that is bothering me - after starting the computer in the bottom right corner I can see USB icon even though in my opinion nothing is connected. I click on it, and there is no device connected. I can see only 3 dots.

The device manager shows that it is a disk. I tried to reinstall the system - the situation was unchanged. Drivers are up-to-date (I've used Live Update 6  from MSI)

**Is this an SD card reader? Is there a chance to hide it?** Generally, I do not know how to deal with it. Below there are a few screenshots. I will be grateful for your support.

[Here is what I see after the click (3 dots)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f148s.jpg)

[Here is what I can see in BIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAYLq.jpg)

[There is a disk...but there is no device connected ("Brak nośnika" in Polish)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bElAP.jpg)

[This is what I see in device manager - there is a mass storage and strange disk with a letter G](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36z1V.jpg)

["Show hidden devices" checked and...there is a disk shown which in my opinion doesn't exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvqYF.jpg)

Comment: Could you switch Device Manager to "View by connection" and find the mysterious device there?

Comment: @grawity 

I've made Print Scrren of Device Manager ("View by connection") - https://pasteboard.co/IeYAuyS.jpg. Problem is this "H" thing. It's not really a disk. I don't know what it is. And it's in Polish but I can translate it if you need.

Comment: @grawity I've checked BIOS and I've found some interesting thing. It looks like the front panel (one with the SD card reader) is recognized as a "Generic, Mass Storage Device". Photos - https://pasteboard.co/If59OKs.jpg and https://pasteboard.co/If5a2id.jpg


Now I'm wondering - is this thing is normal? I've never had such issues with my older computers.

Comment: Many SD card readers (and indeed practically all desktop-PC front-panel card readers) are USB removable drives, yes... although if H: was actually such a device, it'd show up in its normal place in the Device Manager (e.g. under ACPI PC → USB EHCI controller), while your screenshot shows it in an odd place. Can you open the device's "properties" window and find "Device instance" paths under the Advanced tab?

Comment: @grawity

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right - 

USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_MASS&PROD_STORAGE_DEVICE&REV__\125D20140310&0

And here is print screen - https://pasteboard.co/If92KI1.jpg. "Właściwości" means Properties and "Ścieżka wystąpienia urządzenia" is device instance path.

Comment: @grawity
I've checked this reader with one card. It's working. But after I safely remove the card I found out that there is no possibility to read the card again. If  I'm putting the card inside the reader and there is no reaction. Nothing. Whatsmore, this icon in the bottom right corner had dissapeard and in the device manager section there is one problem with USB connection. https://pasteboard.co/IfqdMTq.jpg

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is this "H" thing. It's not really a disk. I don't know what it is.

At first I thought it looked odd that the device shows up right at root in Device Manager, but it turns out that's normal, it's how *all* removable disks appear in there. (These items represent a portable device for Windows Media Player – that's a separate object from the "disk" itself.)

> Is this an SD card reader?

Most likely yes. Front-panel card readers on desktop PCs are almost always USB-attached. (In laptops they may be either USB-based or directly PCI-based.)

It is completely normal that an empty reader shows up as an empty drive, because it is indeed still connected (it's the same as how all other fixed-reader, removable-media drives work).

(Although not all card readers work that way – some of them *might* completely disappear from the USB bus when the card is removed.)

> Is there a chance to hide it?

In Device Manager, right-click "USB Mass Storage Device" and select "Disable device".

Alternatively, open the PC case and just unplug the reader.

> I've checked this reader with one card. It's working. But after I safely remove the card I found out that there is no possibility to read the card again. If I'm putting the card inside the reader and there is no reaction. Nothing. Whatsmore, this icon in the bottom right corner had dissapeard and in the device manager section there is one problem with USB connection.

The card reader might be broken, or just improperly connected to the motherboard.

I would test it through a Linux "live CD" (e.g. from Ubuntu) – open terminal, run `dmesg -ewL`, insert and remove the card a few times. If it shows the same problem there, then you can be certain it's a hardware issue.

On the other hand, if it *works* on Linux, then the reader may need a special driver (although that would be very unusual)... It might, however, be a general problem with the USB 3.0 drivers.

Comment: I've asked the producer of my computer case about this issue. After some print screens he send me (for free) front panel with USB ports and card reader slot. I've plug it in...and the problem is still here. :) 

I'm guessing that this issue is something involved with connection between motherboard and computer case or maybe it's because of model of my SD card reader.

And of course it may be something with USB drivers but I don't know were I can find proper ones for Windows 10. Operating system is "saying" that my drivers are up to date.